# Testing a nested for loop to match ID and run a function yields wrong result than when I run the method from the Main - JAVA

Tags: java, junit

I have 2 different list of Item objects, one containing a subset of the other (main list of Items). ie, a shopping cart containing a subset of a full list of items offered by an online shop.

I am wanting to iterate through using 2 For loops and run a method when it is found that an item from the cart matches an item from the main list.

I have implemented as such:

```
// Imagine there are 2 populated Lists called FullItemList and ShoppingCartList

for (Item i : FullItemList) {
     for (Item j : ShoppingCartList) {
         if (i.getItemId() == j.getItemId()) {
               i.methodToRun();
         }
     }
}
```

I have proven to myself by throwing in a bunch of Sysout's that the method does in fact work when I run from the `Main` method, however when I come to run a `JUnit` test, it will not reach the innards of the `if` statement.

I have made sure to set up and test the method with the exact same objects that I have tested manually with, but still nothing...

**Updated with test class**

```
@Test
    public void refundSaleBySaleTest() throws Exception {
        store.refundSale(exampleSale);
        assertEquals(1, item.getTotalSold());
        assertEquals(21, item.getStockNum());
        assertEquals(14.99, customer.getAccount(),0.0001);
        assertEquals(0, store.getNumberSales());
    }
```

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: What is the type of item ID? If it is a reference type than it should be compared with `equals` instead of `==`.

Comment: add your test class / method

Comment: The ID's are ints, so nothing fancy. Updated with the test class, but it is expecting a Sale item, which holds an array of Items, a LocalDateTime and an int